# Derivation of continued fraction for the incomplete beta function?

Tags: reference-request, beta-function

Where can I find a derivation for this continued fraction representation of the incomplete beta function: http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17#v? I would like to have a reference to the papers where this continued fraction is derived and/or its properties (convergence, error, etc) are studied. Or if you can provide such an analysis in an answer that would be fine too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177731751) I must say, that from a lay-man's point of view. The incomplete beta function's approximations seem to be sensitive to what values you pick. Thus there are actually multiple continued fractions that have to be used if one wants to maintain efficiency. [This has a more involved discussion of usability](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176344629).